# Autofac with generic services and repository

Tags: c#, autofac, generic-programming

I'am facing an issue with the architecture set in place while trying to use Autofac.

Error message encountered is the following:

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'xx.xx.xxxxxxx.HomeController' can be invoked with the available
>   services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'xx.Service.Common.IGenericService`2[xx.Common.Models.EntCountry,System.Int32]
>   countryService' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(xx.Service.Common.IGenericService`2[xx.Common.Models.EntCountry,System.Int32])'.

**Repository Interface and Class**

```
 public interface IGenericRepository<T,TId> 
        where T: class , IEntity<TId>
    {...}

 public abstract class GenericRepository<T, TId> : IGenericRepository<T, TId>  
        where T : class, IEntity<TId>
        where TId : class {}
```

**Service Interface and Class**

```
 public interface IGenericService<T,TId> where T : class , IEntity<TId> 
    {...}



public abstract class GenericService<T, TId> : IGenericService<T, TId>  
        where T : class, IEntity<TId> 
        where TId : class{...}
```

**Controller Code**

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {

    private readonly IGenericService<EntCountry, int> _countryService;

    public HomeController(IGenericService<EntCountry, int> countryService)
    {
        _countryService = countryService;
    }

    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var countries = _countryService.GetAll();

        return View();
    }
}
```

My Autofac configuration for services and repository is the following:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("XX.Data"))
                   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                   .AsSelf()
     .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies)
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();





 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("XX.Service"))
                   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                   .AsSelf()
                   .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies)
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I tried to use the Register Generic method, but I still got the same error

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericRepository<,>))
                .As(typeof(IGenericRepository<,>))
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerDependency();
```

Thanks for your help.

best regards.

Comment: does `XX.Service` assembly contains a concrete implementation of `GenericService`

Comment: yes it is! XX.Service contains the GenericService and IGenericService.

Comment: yes but `GenericService` is an abstract class. *Autofac* can instanciate an abstract class it needs a concrete class inheriting from it

Comment: Exactly, I removed abstract from my repository but i still got the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that `IGenericService<EntCountry, Int32>` is not registered.

Because `GenericService` is abstract the first solution would be to have an implementation of such a class

```
public class FooService : GenericService<Foo, Int32> 
{ }
```

Then *Autofac* will register `FooService` as `IGenericService<Foo, Int32>`

If you don't want to have an implementation but only use `GenericService<T, TId>` you will have to remove the `abstract` modifier and change how you register your type in *Autofac*.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to register an open generic type when scanning assemblies. There is an active open issue about this in Autofac Github : [Support registering open generic types when scanning assemblies](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/215)

The easiest solution is to register this type manually

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericService<,>))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

If it is not possible have a look at the Github issue there is some solution you could play with.

---

There will also be another issue with the code provided. The `IGenericService<T, TId>` has a class constraint (`where TId : class`) but in the exception `TId` is a `Int32` wich is not valid for the .net runtime. You should remove the class constraint or change the type of `TId`.

Comment: Thanks for you help Cyril!